# TYPO3 Solr extension and facets

Tags: solr, typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have a small question about TYPO3 solr facets.At present in my website I have 6 different indexing configuration available. Two of them are custom extension table's and one is tt_news and rest of the 3 are pages table with some custom condition. I managed to add this using ***additionalWhereClause*** . My requirement is add facets in front-end . I have manged to do this also . See below for the Typoscript

```
facets { 
    type {
        field = type
        renderingInstruction = CASE
        renderingInstruction {
            key.field = optionValue

            pages = TEXT
            pages.value = Search Units     

            search_units = TEXT
            search_units..value = Search Units   ( This is also pages but I can see this facets in frontend)  

            expertise_offered = TEXT
            expertise_offered.value = EXpertise 

            tt_news = TEXT
            tt_news.value = News

            user_xxxxxxxxxxx_event = TEXT
            user_xxxxxxxxxxx_event.value = XXXX Events

            user_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_officer = TEXT
            user_xxxxxxxxxxxxx_officer.value = XXXXX Officers 

        }   
    }
```

In front end I can see only 4 facets , the 3 pages indexes are grouped into one. So my question is , Is it possible that we can separate these configuration and show them as independent facets in front-end ? ie the above configuration should return 6 facets in fornt-end .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `type`-field in the solr index only has 4 values, one for pages, 1 each for the two custom tables, and 1 for news. In order to get 6 facets, you need to have 6 different values in the field the faceting is done on.

I'm not sure if you can define the value of the `type`-field for each indexing configuration (doesn't look that way when looking into the [documentation](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Tx_solrindex#tx_solrindex)).

Anyway, there is another way: Add another (dynamic) field to the documents, on which you can do the facetting:

1. Add a new field in the `fields` part of each indexing configuration, using SOLR-type `*_stringS` (see [Wiki of the extension for dynamic fields](https://forge.typo3.org/projects/extension-solr/wiki/Dynamic_Fields)). That type does not do text analysis, so it should be usable for faceting.
2. Change the field you do the faceting on to the new field.